# Update data from firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had done the insertion of using uid which created from firebase email authentication under the node of user but I want to edit and update the personal detail and then I retrieve error come out. My code cannot retrieve the specific user data after login. Please advice me if anyone had solution for this. Thanks.

[image]

So how am I gonna retrieve the specific data and update it?

```
private EditText ppw, ppn, pa, ppc;
private TextView un, page;
private Button pbt;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference dref;
private FirebaseUser ur;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private String uid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_personal_profile);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dref = db.getReference("users");

    //ur = auth.getCurrentUser();
    //uid = ur.getUid();

    un = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Pun);
    ppw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ppw);

    page = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Page);

    ppn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ppn);
    pa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pa);
    ppc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ppc);

    pbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Psbt);

    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String eun = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                un.setText(eun);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do not store password in db. Password is stored in user auth, and if you need to store password, use password hashing!